# Join two tables using common column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got three database tables that are connected trough each other but not directly. Here are the tables:

```
Table one
-----------
id
rank
table_two_id

Table two
-----------
id
amount
table_three_id

Table three
-----------
id
name
```

So each row in table one can be directly linked to the row in the third table.
I need to get some columns from table_one plus the name column from the third column.

I've tried many combinations so far, but this one seems to be the most promising so far, however I can't get it to work :

```
    select (select s.table_three_id 
            from table_two s 
            where s.id = r.table_two_id) as three_id, 
    table_three.name 
    from table_one r
    INNER JOIN table_three ON (three_id = table_three.id);
```

I get an error saying column `three_id` doesn't exist. How do I get the info from the third table based on key from `table_one` trough `table_two`.

Comment: None of your tables has a column named `three_id` ...

Comment: and none of you tables is named `table_three`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this way:

```
select 
 r.*,
 table_three.name 
from table_one r
INNER JOIN table_two s ON s.id           = r.table_two_id
INNER JOIN table_three ON table_three.id = s.table_three.id;
```